# PHP code display in browser instead of executing it

Tags: php, apache

I have just configured the PHP 5.3.8 from PHP.net and apache 2.2.20 from apachelaunge on Windows 7.

Every thing done very well.

I have tried `PHP -i` from the command line and it show me all PHP infomarmation.

But when I have tried to execute the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` , then browsers shows me the same content as in php file but not the actual PHP execution result.

I have added Directory Index also like below:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

I am not getting where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm posting this answer because my Virtualmin/Webmin admin interface decided it was a good idea to disable my PHP engine.. took me a while to find the solution, so I thought I'd share it with you guys:*

Also, be sure to check that none of your website config files related to this specific host or virtualhost have any php_admin_value's in them that turn off PHP, like this:

```
php_admin_value engine Off
```

When in doubt, comment it...

```
# php_admin_value engine Off
```

And restart your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Is this phpInfo result any different from the one you are getting from a different server? May be an older version of PHP? The two might not give the same output.